# Optimize generation of Mysql bulk query

Tags: grails, groovy

I´m migrating data from one database to another via a script.
I don´t have the posibility to export as csv or something directly on the db server.
So i´m made a script to read the rows from one, and insert bulk on the mysql.
The base problem is that convert the list that recibe from the server to the format that needs to Mysql to do the bulk insert, generate the aux on the script takes too much time, like 40 seconds for 2500 values.
But really not sure if can make a big change, because really don´t found any obvious overhead on the code, obviously I have made two eachs but really I don´t found other way.

```
  def query= """SELECT * FROM tablex """.toString()
  def   fullRowResults = sql.rows(query) as List
  fullRowResults =fullRowResults.collate(2500)
fullRowResults.each{ frr ->
  def aux=""
  frr.each{
  def aux2= it.values()
  aux2= aux2.collect{
    it.replaceAll("'","")
  }
  aux2=aux2.join("','")
  aux2="('"+aux2+"'),"
  aux+=aux2
}
```

Then whit aux generated, I insert in on MySQL

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, it's far to difficult to understand what you're doing. Remember that we don't have your database, we can't run your code, so we rely on clarity to understand what is happening. Please demonstrate **example** output. For instance, having the example output of `sql.rows(query) as List` will go a long way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, can´t get fixed this, but implemented it in a quartz job,made it concurrent, and deployed 5 vms and get the process done in a day.
Brute force.